# How to sort by column and next row and order them by another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with four columns: `ID`, `isError`, `SolidLine` and `HighestError`.

Each row is related to another row by `SolidLine` column. So we have two related rows in the table.

For example, rows with `ID` 1 and 2 have relation by `SolidLine`(5).

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      ID      |    isError     |      SolidLine   |    HighestError
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       1      |     0          |        5         |     1
|       2      |     0          |        5         |     1
|       3      |     0          |        8         |     1
|       4      |     0          |        8         |     1
|       5      |     1          |        10        |     50 
|       6      |     0          |        10        |     1
|       7      |     1          |        4         |     80
|       8      |     0          |        4         |     1
|       9      |     1          |        7         |     80
|      10      |     0          |        7         |     1
|      11      |     0          |        3         |     1 
|      12      |     0          |        3         |     1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to sort a table by the following condition:

> If `isError` is 1, take the next row by `SolidLine`, then order by
>   HighestError

So the wish result should look like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|      ID      |    isError     |      SolidLine   |    HighestError
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|       7      |     1          |        4         |   80
|       8      |     0          |        4         |   1
|       9      |     1          |        7         |   80
|       10     |     0          |        7         |   1
|       5      |     1          |        10        |   50
|       6      |     0          |        10        |   1
|       1      |     0          |        5         |   1
|       2      |     0          |        5         |   1
|       3      |     0          |        8         |   1
|       4      |     0          |        8         |   1
|       11     |     0          |        3         |   1
|       12     |     0          |        3         |   1 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*The first row becomes the first row as `HighestError` has maximum value in the table `isError` equals 1. Then the next row goes with `ID` = 8 as it `SolidLine` has the same value `SolidLine` of row with `ID` = 7.*

*`SolidLine` are pairs always together and does not depend upon `isError` column.*

*So the pair of rows tied by `SolidLine` should always be together.*

I tried the following queries, but it gives wrong result:

```
--it breaks SolidLine ordering. 
SELECT ID, isError, SolidLine, HighestError
FROM SolidThreads
ORDER BY SolidLine, isError, HighestError desc, id
```

and:

```
SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SolidLine ORDER BY isError DESC) [RowNumber],
ID, isError, SolidLine, HighestError
FROM SolidThreads
ORDER BY HighestError desc, id
```

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I do it?

Comment: Why is id 7 first?  Can you explain the output one row at a time?

Comment: Are solidLine pairs always together, or only if there is an error?

Comment: @MatBailie as `isError` equals 1 and `HighestError` has maximum value in the table. Then the next row goes with `ID` = 8 as it `SolidLine` has the same value `SolidLine` of row with `ID` = 7.

Comment: @GregViers `SolidLine` are pairs always together.

Comment: What's wrong with `ORDER BY HighestError desc, id`?

Comment: @AaronDietz it breaks `SolidLine` ordering.

Comment: In your desired result, why is solidline 5 before 8 and 8 before 3?

Comment: @GregViers cause they ordered by ID, but it does not really matter. What I need is to keep pairs and order them by `isError` and `HighestError`.

Comment: I believe you that it doesn't work on your real data, but it works on your sample data.  Add an instance where it doesn't work. 
 See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c3ddc/1/0

Comment: To paraphrase. Solid lines with an error in the "group" first, then "groups" with highest `highesterror` first, then rows with an error first, then lowest id first?

Comment: @MatBailie yeah

Comment: @AaronDietz I am sorry, but I've given not correst sample data, but correct condition. Please, review my sample data. I've seen your SQL fiddle, but it gives the wrong result with updated sample data.

Comment: Does each pair always share the same highest error?

Comment: You changing the data while I was walking home from the bus made a right mess of my testing ;)  My answer appears to work for your data in the manner I believe you have described.

Comment: @SQLChao no, it doesn’t

Comment: @MatBailie I am so sorry for my stupid mistake. Could you see again?

Comment: @StepUp - My current answer uses your current data and gives your current results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you describe it, you should be able to do this by...

- adding a column for "This Solid Line Includes an Error Row"
- adding a column for "The max error for this Solid Line"
- using CASE expressions to change the sorting based on error state

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84e7a/1

```
WITH
  SolidThreadsSummary AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(isError     ) OVER (PARTITION BY SolidLine)   AS SolidLineHasError,
    MAX(highestError) OVER (PARTITION BY SolidLine)   AS SolidLineMaxError
  FROM
    SolidThreads
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  SolidThreadsSummary
ORDER BY
  SolidLineHasError DESC,  -- Not really necessary for your data
  SolidLineMaxError DESC,
  CASE WHEN SolidLineHasError > 0 THEN SolidLine ELSE 1 END,
  isError DESC,
  id
```

This may be a little more robust if pairs are not always consecutive by id (for the pairs containing no error)...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/84e7a/2

```
WITH
  SolidThreadsSummary AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(isError     ) OVER (PARTITION BY SolidLine)   AS SolidLineHasError,
    MAX(highestError) OVER (PARTITION BY SolidLine)   AS SolidLineMaxError,
    MIN(id          ) OVER (PARTITION BY SolidLine)   AS SolidLineMinID
  FROM
    SolidThreads
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  SolidThreadsSummary
ORDER BY
  SolidLineHasError DESC,
  SolidLineMaxError DESC,
  CASE WHEN SolidLineHasError > 0 THEN SolidLine ELSE 1 END,
  isError DESC,
  SolidLineMinID,
  id
;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to sort keeping the SolidLines together, and ordering those groups first by HighestError then by the lowest ID in the group, then within the group show errors first. Assuming that's what you want, I would do this with a derived table:

```
ID, isError, SolidLine, HighestError
FROM SolidThreads INNER JOIN
(SELECT SolidLine, MAX(Highesterror) as sorting_HighestError, MIN(ID) as Sorting_Id
    FROM SolidThreads GROUP BY SolidLine) as Sorting_DT
ON Sorting_DT.SolidLine = SolidThreads.SolidLine
ORDER BY sorting_HighestError DESC, Sorting_Id, isError Desc, Id
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `ID` is always sequential for each `SolidLine` pair, you can simply do [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3e88c/2/0):

```
SELECT T.*
FROM yourTable T
JOIN (SELECT SolidLine, MAX(HighestError) MaxError
      FROM yourTable
      GROUP BY SolidLine) T2 ON T.SolidLine = T2.SolidLine
ORDER BY MaxError DESC, ID
```